# Dynamic programming solution for implementing a Primitive Calculator

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a problem from the Algorithmic Toolbox course on Coursera. The problem description is as follows:

**You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with the current number
x: multiply x by 2, multiply x by 3, or add 1 to x. Your goal is given a positive integer n, find the
minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.**

I implemented a recursive solution and used memoization, and managed to solve some test cases but I keep failing at a certain one (they don't tell me on which input I failed).

Here's my solution:
https://codeshare.io/aYWoPL

I have no idea, why my code isn't working as supposed. I do not want you to give me the code, I can find that on the web if I want to, I just want some insights on why my code isn't working! Thanks in advance.

I searched the previous questions but found no satisfying solution, so sorry if this is a duplicate to some of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have the special case `n == 10`, and also duplicate statements. But the real crucial mistake is the use of `else if` - a number can be a multiple of *both* `3` and `2`. You need to take the minimum steps required out of all three operations:

```
long long numOp (int n, long long num_operations[]) {
   if (n <= 1) return 0;

   if (num_operations[n - 2] > 0)
      return num_operations[n - 2];

   long long min = numOp(n - 1, num_operations);
   if (n % 3 == 0) {
      long long temp = numOp(n / 3, num_operations);
      if (temp < min) min = temp;
   }
   if (n % 2 == 0) {
      long long temp = numOp(n / 2, num_operations);
      if (temp < min) min = temp;
   }

   return (num_operations[n - 2] = 1 + min);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the same variable "temp" for storing both values of numOp(n/3, num_operations) and numOp(n/2, num_operations) ?

Comment: @AmrMustafa it doesn't matter because they are in different scopes (different if-statement blocks)

Comment: Yes right that makes sense, but why do you use "n - 2" as index, shouldn't it be n ?

Comment: @AmrMustafa since we return 0 directly for 0 and 1 (and negative numbers which are invalid), we can save two memory spaces. But you can leave it out if you want.